# Cannot disable breaking on IOException in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I am observing the weird problem. In the Exception Settings, I have System.IO.IOException listed and unchecked, which means that the exception is explicitly disabled and the debugger must not break on this exception. And in general, this works. However, in the specific case, when the exception message is "The operation could not be completed. A retry should be performed" and the exception is thrown from the FileStream constructor, execution stops anyway. This makes debugging plain impossible because the exception happens in multiple threads in a loop (that's how the code is expected to work).

The code is C#, targeting .NET 4.0.

Does anybody have an idea if it's a bug of the debugger or I am missing something?

Comment: How can we reproduce this behaviour ([mcve])? Which cosntructor to use and what kind of situation causes the exception to be thrown?

Comment: @RenéVogt If it were clear how to reproduce it, most likely, there would be no question (at least in its current form). The error originates somewhere in .NET internals, and the question is if anyone observed such situation before and maybe had additional information or observations about the conditions, in which the issue happens.

Comment: I thought your question was about why VS keeps breaking at this exception. My question was about how to get the `FileStream` constructor to throw this exception to see if my IDE shows the same bevaviour in that case as yours.

Comment: @RenéVogt What (most likely) happens inside is that the OS, based on the filesystem driver response, returns the "retry" result code in the FileStream's call. I don't know how to artificially create such a situation without going into the kernel, so reproducing is not easy here. The problem is random but frequent, and this makes the investigation even trickier.

Comment: Hi,could you please share a minimal reproducible example with us?And it will help us troubleshoot your issue quickly.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Got it :) I will try to find a way to reproduce it. we are a vendor of the device drivers, so the issues has its roots in the driver that declines the request (for legitimate reason). Thus I need to find a way to provide a simple test case.